# FirebasePushNotification Amber Alert like notification

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, push-notification

I have recently implemented the Plugin.FirebasePushNotification plugin and it works as expected for normal notifications. I now need to create a notification that would have a similar impact as an Amber Alert or severe weather alert. I would like it to pop up on the device (Android, iOS, tablets and phones) so that it must be attended to. I've reviewed the documentation for the plug-in and the only guidance is setting the importance level to MAX which is helpful but I want to go further. I read that Apple has a process to get this level of service, but I would need to apply for it. Does Android have a similar service? I am first looking for a way within the bounds of standard notifications to achieve this. To start I am looking for some best practices in doing these kinds of notifications.
The app will be used by multiple customers in a SaaS environment and the alerts would need to be targeted only to single customer based on the event that needs alerting. So targeting a channel may not be the best.
Any guidance would be very helpful

Comment: For the use case you describe you are going to be limited to the standard notifications.

Comment: @Paulw11 I was afraid of that, but I will investigate further as the condition to be alerted could put people's safety at risk.